# Questions about Amazon' AWS Free Trial

Tags: amazon-ec2

Ok this might sound kind of paranoid.
But we are about to move my company's infrastructure to Amazons EC2 services.

We would be testing things by starting with the 12months free trial services.

My question is, are there any clause to be aware of with regards the Free Trail?

Things like ease of quitting the free trial and exporting your Data out of the system?

I have read the SLA and Terms of Service and nothing was mentioned about this.

Just want to be on the safe side.

Anybody has an opinion on this?

Answer (score 2):

Quitting the free trial is easy, you can delete your account or subscribe to pay from web services interface.

Exporting data out of AWS is easy as well; it's just the same as transferring data to any other server. Personally I'd use rsync over an SSH connection.

Judging by your questions, it sounds like you're on shared hosting or a managed server. AWS requires more knowledge to get going; you'll need to know how to configure servers yourself.